# Checkbox image toggle in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need some guidance on creating a `UITableViewCell` that has an image on the left which can be toggled. The image should be tappable and act as a toggle (checkbox).

My parts I'm struggling with are:

1. How do I detect taps on the image and handle those differently to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?
2. How do I change the image without performing a `[tableView reloadData]`?

Comment: hi rein, how can you make this image for your question ?Is there any software available for this?

Comment: Where do you get the check mark icon?

Comment: Can I also bump where you got that checkmark icon from?

Comment: @rein how did you create that back button(top-left)?

Comment: @London this isn't from my app - it's from an app called Groceries. http://sophiestication.com/groceries/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy.

Just create a new subclass of UIControl and put it all in there (no need for a separate controller.)  Let's call it ToggleImageControl.

```
@interface ToggleImageControl : UIControl
{
   BOOL selected;
   UIImageView *imageView;
   UIImage *normalImage;
   UIImage *selectedImage;
}
```

Create a ToggleImageControl for each cell, and add it at the appropriate position.

```
ToggleImageControl *toggleControl = [[ToggleImageControl alloc] initWithFrame: <frame>];
toggleControl.tag = indexPath.row;  // for reference in notifications.
[cell.contentView addSubview: toggleControl];
```

Add a UIImageView to contain the image.  Add a target for the touch event.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"normal.png"];
   selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"selected.png"];
   imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: normalImage];
   // set imageView frame
   [self.view addSubview: imageView];

[self addTarget: self action: @selector(toggleImage) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Set the UIImageView's image property to update the image; that will trigger the redraw without side-effects.

```
- (void) toggleImage
{
   selected = !selected;
   imageView.image = (selected ? selectedImage : normalImage); 

   // Use NSNotification or other method to notify data model about state change.
   // Notification example:
   NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: self.tag forKey: @"CellCheckToggled"];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"CellCheckToggled" object: self userInfo: dict];

}
```

You will obviously need to massage some stuff.  You probably want to pass in the two image names to make it more reusable, and also I'd recommend specifying the notification name string from outside the object as well (assuming you are using the notification method.)

Comment: This is great! Thanks. One question, when the toggleImage control is tapped the tap won't be bubbled to the UITableViewControl's didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Correct?

Comment: No, the button intercepts it and prevents it being seen by the cell.

Comment: Can you also just make this control an empty frame and use the existing cell.imageView property to draw the actual image?

Comment: sehugg: Probably.  Almost anything can be done by layering controls.

Comment: When scrolling tableview images dissappear. It is not clearly working.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an implementation of the "override touchesBegan:" approach I'm using that is simple and seems to work well.

Just include this class in your project and create and configure a `TouchIconTableViewCell` instead of a `UITableView` cell in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

TouchIconTableViewCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TouchIconTableViewCell;

@protocol TouchIconTableViewCellDelegate<NSObject>

@required
- (void)tableViewCellIconTouched:(TouchIconTableViewCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end

@interface TouchIconTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    id<TouchIconTableViewCellDelegate> touchIconDelegate;       // note: not retained
    NSIndexPath *touchIconIndexPath;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TouchIconTableViewCellDelegate> touchIconDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *touchIconIndexPath;

@end
```

TouchIconTableViewCell.m:

```
#import "TouchIconTableViewCell.h"

@implementation TouchIconTableViewCell

@synthesize touchIconDelegate;
@synthesize touchIconIndexPath;

- (void)dealloc {
    [touchIconIndexPath release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint location = [((UITouch *)[touches anyObject]) locationInView:self];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.imageView.frame, location)) {
        [self.touchIconDelegate tableViewCellIconTouched:self indexPath:self.touchIconIndexPath];
        return;
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Each time you create or re-use the cell, set the `touchIconDelegate` and `touchIconIndexPath` properties. When your icon is touched, the delegate will be invoked. Then you can update the icon or whatever.

Comment: sorry but what exactly do you mean by "set the touchIconDelegate and touchIconIndexPath properties"?

Comment: For example:// Create cell
    TouchIconTableViewCell *cell = (TouchIconTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[TouchIconTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease];
    cell.touchIconDelegate = self;
    cell.touchIconIndexPath = indexPath;

Comment: I like it.  Seemed a bit simpler than creating another control to throw in my custom table cell.

Answer (score 4):

So the "..obviously need to massage some stuff.." comment means "...this code doesn't work...".

So

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
```

should be

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
 if ( self = [super initWithFrame: frame] ){
  normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"toggleImageNormal.png"];
  selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"toggleImageSelected.png"];
  imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: normalImage];

 // set imageView frame
  [self addSubview: imageView];

  [self addTarget: self action: @selector(toggleImage) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
 }

 return self;
}
```

As `- (void) viewDidLoad` never gets called.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Apple uploaded "TableMultiSelect" as sample codes on iOS Developer Program since 2011-10-12.

Multiple selection in edit mode can be enabled by this code.

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Though it can be used only from iOS5.

Several hours I could not find this sample code in Stack Overflow, so I added this info to this post.

Comment: This is some very nice sample code. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Answer (score 1):

There's an even EASIER way to do this, if you override touchesBegan: you need to do an if statement to decide if it's within the check marks proximity, if it's not call `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]` and it will act as though it was selected.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar (starring a favorite) like this, but I think you're demanding a lot from the thumbs of iPhone users with the cell directing people to another view. First of all, I would check out the detail disclosure option on cells. One of the options is a pre-made arrow button that you can attach to. Your call.

You might be able to get away with catching the didSelectRowAtIndexPath event and then doing some other logic instead of redirecting if the touch was on your checkbox, although I don't know how you would get the position.  This means you might need to find a way to get ahold of the touch event before it calls didSelectRowAtIndex path, which I'm not quite sure how to do. Have you worked with handling touchesBegan and the like yet?

Comment: The screenshot I linked is from the Groceries app by Sophiestication (http://www.sophiestication.com/groceries/). I know it's possible because that app does it and it works quite well.

I've been avoiding creating my own UITableViewCell class - so far I've got away with putting views in the contentView. To implement touchesBegan correctly I think I have no choice but to create my own UITableViewCell class. How did you write the code to star your rows as favorites?