# How can I use images provided by the iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, image

First, let me state what brought this question about: I saw the green checkmark icon in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171476) and I would like to use it in my own application. However, since it looks so much like the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` my assumption is that this green checkmark icon is provided by the iPhone OS in some form or fashion.

So, my question is: how can I use the green checkmark icon and/or other OS-provided images in my own applications?

As a side question: where can I find a list of the OS-provided images (if they even exist)?

Thanks very much for any input :-)

Comment: You could extract them using https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor and then add them manually to your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not one of the standard images.
To see what you have available, you can add a UIBarButton in interface builder and try different system icons.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to accept this as the correct answer :-)