# iPhone Checkboxes à la Mail

Tags: iphone, cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder, checkbox

After reading the iPhone Human Interface Guidelines, I notice there's little mention of checkboxes in the style that one may encounter them on the desktop or web.

Checkboxes are generally handled by `UISwitch`s on the iPhone, but for an app I'm presently working on, they're really not the right control. Instead, the control you'll see in Mail is a much better fit:

[image: Checkboxes in Mail]

*Actual mail blanked out. Obviously.*

How would I go about using these checkbox controls in my app? Are they standard, or will I need to imitate them with a custom control?

Cheers friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't subclass UIControl. What you want is a UIButton of "custom" type. Load it with your "unlit" image in IB (or programmatically in `-viewDidLoad`--you can set it appropriate to its data there too, if you came here with that property already "checked").

Point its touchUpInside event at a method called `-(void)toggleCheckBox`, and in that method, toggle whatever setting you're toggling (probably a BOOL property of the objects you're listing), and toggle the "lit/unlit" status of the button image by using its `-setImage: forState:` method. Use the control state `UIControlStateNormal`.

I do something similar where I let people poke a button to toggle the "favorite" status of the thing ("thisEvent"--a member of an array of local cultural/arts events) they're looking at:

```
- (IBAction)toggleFavorite {

    if (self.thisEvent.isFavorite == YES) {
        self.thisEvent.isFavorite = NO;
        [self.favoriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFavorite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        self.thisEvent.isFavorite = YES;
        [self.favoriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"isFavorite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

Comment: +1, although testing a BOOk against YES is arguable, and I'd make it '-(IBAction)toggleFavorite:(id)sender' and '[sender setImage:...]'.

Comment: Maybe so re using (id)sender. I like to be explicit about testing bools against YES--I find it much clearer reading it later.

Comment: I have had some great answers to this question but I'll have to give this one to you Dan. Thanks for your answer; this is exactly how I ended up doing it and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a custom control. It won't be difficult since `UIControl` already has  'selected', 'highlighted' and 'state' properties at your disposal. You'll just need to draw and toggle appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain there is no standard way to do this. However it's fairly simple to achieve, all you need is two images, one for each state. I would probably do something simple like subclass UIImageView and add a `setState:(BOOL)theState` method, which would then simply select the relevant image.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather subclass UITableViewCell then UIImageView. UITableViewCell allready comes with selected/unselected states and handlers for editmodes etc.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, you'll need to subclass `UIControl`. The actual process was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171476/checkbox-image-toggle-in-uitableviewcell) w little while ago.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a description of another way to do this using the same image/method that the Mail app uses:

http://networkpx.blogspot.com/2009/07/multiple-row-selection-with-uitableview.html

but as this implements undocumented features of the iOS SDK, it may not be best for apps intended for the official App Store.