# checkbox in UItableviewcell

Tags: iphone

I taking reference from url
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171476/checkbox-image-toggle-in-uitableviewcell)

I am able to bring the checkbox on tableview.
Now on button click i want to check which checkbox is selected. HOw can i do so?

In the url "Amagrammer" suggested to use NSnotification, can any one provide me an tutorial for that.

```
    - (void) toggleImage
{
   selected = !selected;
   imageView.image = (selected ? selectedImage : normalImage); 

   // Use NSNotification or other method to notify data model about state change.
   // Notification example:
   NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: self.tag forKey: @"CellCheckToggled"];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"CellCheckToggled" object: self userInfo: dict];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller or somewhere you handle the data
You add a observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(YOUR__FUNCTION) name:@"CellCheckToggled" object:nil];
```

Then you can do sth in **YOUR__FUNCTION** with your userInfo

```
-(void)YOUR__FUNCTION: (NSNotification*) aNotification
{
dict = [aNotification userInfo];

}
```