# toggle checkbox image in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've been having a problem of adding a checkbox image to my uitableviewcell and toggle between checked and unchecked image.

My simple code is:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)todoTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.todoTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

if (!cell) { 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [self.todoList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

return cell;
}
```

and i try to add in the solution in from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171476/checkbox-image-toggle-in-uitableviewcell)

But i don't know where shall i put the
`interface ToggleImageControl : UIControl`
I assume i put it in the same header file as my viewcontroller?

also i try to put in

```
ToggleImageControl *toggleControl = [[ToggleImageControl alloc] initWithFrame: <frame>];
toggleControl.tag = indexPath.row;  // for reference in notifications.
[cell.contentView addSubview: toggleControl];
```

into my code above, i will get a `ToggleImageControl` reference error because of the implementation of the interface is not found, how can i fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish such modifications in look and behaviour is to write your own subclass of `UITableViewCell`. `UIButton` actually has toggling feature built in via `selected` property.

Answer (score 0):

KakoSquid is correct.  It looks like you might need to spend some time getting to know how classes and subclasses are built.

In your case it sounds like you have made a new interface section for your ToggleImageControl in the .h file but you need to put an @implementation section in your .m file.

In many situations you will make a new file set for a new class.  (.h & .m files).  In this case a toggle image is something you could reuse across other projects so it would make sense to break it out into its own file.

But, you can add the interface and implementation into any existing flies as you see fit.  Just make sure to #import the correct files where you are using them.