# UIButton inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I have 2 UIButtons inside a myCustomCell Class which is a subclass of UITableViewCell.

[image: My Custom Cell]

The black Outline is the **cell** (UITableViewCell *) which is returned by '**cellForRowAtIndex**'.
This **cell** contains '**myCustomCell**' as a subview. '**myCustomCell**' has two UIButtons and the following properties :

```
    backgroundcolor = clearColor 
    opaque = NO
```

On clicking anywhere in the cell except for the two Red Boxes(UI Buttons), I want the '**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**' be triggered. 
But if the user clicks on the UIButton, only the selector for the target needs to be triggered, and not the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: may be you have added a view over cell and that's absorbing your toches over cell. It's just a hypothesis.

Comment: It should be working fine if you added the target and action to the button. It should not pass the touch event to the cell if you tap the button. IS user interaction enabled?

Comment: @kyuubi- are button are taking action...?

Comment: @Kyuubi - Post You code...We cant guess much

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171476/checkbox-image-toggle-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: Why a custom cell subview in cell?? I didn't get that!

Comment: @MeeraJPai: Rightly pointed out. I was adding (myCustomCell *)myCell as a subview to cell instead of just assigning cell = myCell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you build the  cell as you mentioned above : the **myCustomCell** represent a subview inside the cell and it has two buttons inside it, each button has action, this should work as following; when you click on the button the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** will not work and the button will handle the touch event since the touch hierarchy will be observed by the first action wich is the button and will not continue to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and when you tab every where except buttons the  **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** will handle the touch since there no observer handle this touch event and it will reach the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: I had set myCustomCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO , So that the labels and other unnecessary elements do not block the touch for the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'. Upon setting this property to 'YES', the touch triggers the correct selectors. But the various elements are now blocking the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'.