# How to tap cell's buttons in UITableViewCell without actionning the cell's segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, ios9

My custom cell have 2 buttons, and each custom cell also perform a segue.

The segue is functionning properly, the problem come from the fact that my buttons are never fired.
If I click on them then the segue is fired, but not the button.
How to overcome this?

Here goes the code of how the button's actions are defined :

*In the table view controller*

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CCELL.WISHCELL, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WishCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    let product = products.elements[row]


    // Setup the 2 cell buttons
    cell.removeButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.addToCartButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.removeButton.addTarget(self, action: "removeFromWishList:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.addToCartButton.addTarget(self, action: "addToCart", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

*the functions targette by the selectors are valid, I have no error. Buttons are just never fired.*

If it's not that trivial and more code is needed just ask me!

Comment: cell.selection = none try this

Comment: I don't have the property `selection` on my cells

Comment: all table view Cells have this property , you can check it at story board

Comment: Don't set the action on the button to perform the segues, rather link the segues from the view controller object in the storyboard and use `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your button action code

Comment: The action of performing segue is not on the button. In the storyboard i connected the segue to the cell. The button is supposed to call another action

Comment: Check that the buttons can be placed under the `contentView` of the cell

Comment: The buttons are INSIDE the contentView, should they be outside? I tried to move them but without success, I mean I can't move them out, storyboard sont let me.

Comment: Did you try explicitly declare userInteructionEnabled = YES for cell's contentView and for buttons? What you want to achieve definitely should work, it means you are doing something wrong

Comment: @Injectios Just tried, didn't changed anything :/

Comment: same questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290526/uibutton-inside-uitableviewcell , as a workaround you can disable "selection" for UITableView and put gestures enstead

Comment: @Injectios Yhea, but I think it's not meant to be. Thanks for the solution but I'll keep to my answer I think

Comment: So the segue is happening before the buttons tasks are being executed?  In a sense we just need to have the segue happen later vs first?

Comment: @CalebBach Yhea, it should be this way for this problem to be solved. But now I find my below answer more elegant for iOS.

Comment: @CalebBach If you have a way to do this just post it as answer I'll accept it if it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found so far:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,     editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
    // delete item at indexPath
}
  let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Disable") { (action, indexPath) in
    // share item at indexPath
}

  share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

  return [delete, share]
}
```

Having my actions as swipe buttons, it's more "iOS" style